# Не срабатывает последнее условие в FizzBuzz

Tags: c#

Указываем число `n`. В диапазоне от 1 до `n` выводим каждый элемент, но только стрингой. Если число кратное 3 - заменяем вывод на `"Fizz"`, если кратно 5 - заменяем вывод на `"Buzz"`, а если кратно и 3 и 5 - на `"FizzBuzz"`

В моей реализации первых два условия выполняется, третье не выполняется никогда:

```
static IList<string> FizzBuzz(int n) {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for(int i =1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                result.Add("Fizz");
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
                result.Add("Buzz");
            else if (i % 15 == 0)
                result.Add("FizzBuzz");
            else
                result.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        return result;
}
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
n = 15,
```

Вывод:

```
[
    "1",
    "2",
    "Fizz",
    "4",
    "Buzz",
    "Fizz",
    "7",
    "8",
    "Fizz",
    "Buzz",
    "11",
    "Fizz",
    "13",
    "14",
    **"FizzBuzz"**
]
```

А по факту имеем:

```
 "1",
    "2",
    "Fizz",
    "4",
    "Buzz",
    "Fizz",
    "7",
    "8",
    "Fizz",
    "Buzz",
    "11",
    "Fizz",
    "13",
    "14",
    **"Fizz"**
```

Как пофиксить, чтобы проверка на кратность на 3 не прерывала проверку на кратность на 3 и 5?
Есть какой либо более шустрый способ решения этой же задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если число делится на 15, то оно делится и на 3 и на 5.

Поэтому проверку делимости на 15 нужно делать раньше:

```
if (i % 15 == 0) result.Add("FizzBuzz");
else if (i % 3 == 0) result.Add("Fizz");
else if (i % 5 == 0) result.Add("Buzz");
else result.Add(i.ToString());
```

P.S. Если убрать все else, то «Fizz» и «Buzz» будут выводиться вместе с «FizzBuzz», что, вроде, нежелательно.
P.S.S. Если ввести в гугл «C# FizzBuzz» найдется множество решений этой задачи ([например](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/fizzbuzz-in-c-sharp)), которые можно сравнить со своим.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что у вас срабатывает первый if (i % 3 == 0) на число 15, т.к. оно соответствует проверке. Я бы предложил проверять сначало на if (i % 15 == 0), а потом уже на 3 и 5.  И тут else if (i % 15 == 0) вы  проверяете, кратное ли это число - 15, а не 3 и 5. Я думаю данное решение будет неплохим.

```
if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)  
    {  
        result.Add("FizzBuzz");  
    }  
    else if (i % 3 == 0)  
    {  
       result.Add("Fizz");  
    }  
    else if (i % 5 == 0)  
    {  
       result.Add("Buzz"); 
    }  
    else  
    {  
        result.Add(i.ToString());  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Прозрение пришло ко мне! Я случайно додумался убрать все else

```
static IList<string> FizzBuzz(int n)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for(int i =1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                result.Add("Fizz");
            if (i % 5 == 0)
                result.Add("Buzz");
            if (i % 15 == 0)
                result.Add("FizzBuzz");
            else
                result.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        return result;
    }
```

Мне кажется выглядит ужасно, но зато работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вопросы задавайте в вопросах. Ответы предназначены только для ответов.

Comment: @Vladimir Neutrino Проблема вашего решения в том, что если срабатывает первый if (i % 3 == 0), то все остальные if будут проверяться тоже. Тут появляеться проблема перформенса. Присмотритесь к решению default locale.  Посмотрите в debug как работает ваш код и ответ будет очевиден